# Drupal database API query - row.update if exists, else row.insert

Tags: mysql, drupal, upsert

I've been trying to run a query in drupal that'll update entries if they already exists or insert a new entry if it doesnt. The code looks like this at the moment:

```
db_query("IF EXISTS (SELECT %d FROM {uc_posten_packages.pid})
UPDATE {uc_posten_packages} SET title = '%s', label = '%s', cost = '%d', length = '%d', width ='%d', height = '%d', weight = '%d'  WHERE pid = %d
ELSE
INSERT INTO {uc_posten_packages} VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d')",$id, $title, $label, $rate, $length, $width, $height, $weight, $id, $id, $title, $label, $rate, $length, $width, $height, $weight);
```

I can't see why that query throws me an error. All the numbers in the error are correct

```
...near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM uc_posten_packages.pid) UPDATE uc_posten_packages ' at line 1 query:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM uc_posten_packages.pid) UPDATE uc_posten_packages SET title = 'vfbv', label = 'bbv', cost = '22', length = '232', width ='22', height = '22', weight = '22' WHERE pid = 1 ELSE INSERT INTO uc_posten_packages VALUES ('1', 'vfbv', 'bbv', '22', '232', '22', '22', '22')
```

Should this query work and/or is there some better way dealing with this in drupal?

Comment: You can't do a thing like that. Take a look at replace syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is cordially called an "upsert" (update otherwise insert), and there is a drupal function for just this: db_merge. Good write-up here: http://drupal.org/node/310085

drupal_write_record() does not automatically perform an "upsert." It always either inserts or updates based on what you pass in only, but not both.

Answer (score 4):

[UPDATE Jan 2013]

This answer refers to an older version of Drupal than the current stable release. Please edit this answer by adding an update section like this with more up-to-date information, as I no longer work with Drupal or keep up with its API changes.

-semperos

[/UPDATE Jan 2013]

You have a couple of options, namely `drupal_write_record` or running a sample query and testing for results. This shouldn't be done in a single SQL query as in your question.

### drupal_write_record (Preferred Method)

The function `drupal_write_record` allows you to specify the table you want to deal with and an object (or associate array) which contains data for each column/field of that table. If you already have the primary key for the row you're trying to update, then you include it as a third parameter to the function, and `drupal_write_record` will automatically use the SQL `UPDATE` command. Otherwise, it defaults to `INSERT`. For example:

```
drupal_write_record('uc_posten_packages', array('title'  => "Foobar",
                                      'label'  => "foobar",
                                      'cost'   => 10,
                                      'length' => 100,));
```

This will `INSERT` a new record with that information. If you had included a third argument of `array($pid)` where `$pid` was the name of the field that acts as primary key for the table, it would have performed an update instead.

This function will only work if the table you're dealing with was defined using [`hook_schema`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema), which should be true of any properly developed Drupal module that has database tables. Since this function uses the schema to ensure it's writing to the database correctly, you should use this function when possible (or when no other more specific functions exist, e.g. `node_save` for node objects).

### Test Query

You can just run a sample query using `db_result(db_query("SELECT..."))`. It returns an empty string if no results are found, which evaluates to false in PHP, so your code could look like:

```
if (db_result(db_query("SELECT * FROM {uc_posten_packages} WHERE pid = %d", $pid))) {
  // UPDATE
} else {
  // INSERT
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is brilliant, but I can't get it to update. I added array($pid) as third argument, but it throws me an error: unsupported type for db_type_placeholder. It works with inserts though, exactly the same query but without a third argument.

Comment: @Toxid I've updated my answer to be more precise. If you look at the api.drupal.org docs for drupal_write_record, the third optional argument should be the *name* of the field that acts as primary key for the table you're working with, not an actual value for a primary key. See the code for the function node_save as an example of both types of drupal_write_record (insert and update) here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6

Comment: Ah, beautiful! I studied the API but I was so sure it was the value of the primary key it was looking for, I forgot the possibility that it could be something else. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at source code of [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6) I see no logic to decide to execute an INSERT or an UPDATE query based on what already is in the DB. Instead I see that it depends on input parameters ($update parameter). So I would correct the answer deleting all the drupal_write_record() part.

Comment: I no longer work in PHP or Drupal. If someone wants to edit my answer with information that is relevant to the latest stable release of Drupal, I'd welcome the edit. In the mean time, I'll edit the answer to clarify that this answer is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

According to [drupal_write_record](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) the operation was an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` you need to know whether the record existed or not before committing the transaction. This is not what drupal_write_record() does. This function just checks it's arguments and issues an update or an insert accordingly. So there is **really no way** to tell if the function did an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

The solution is using [db_merge()](http://drupal.org/node/310085) query, it is a relatively new SQL ANSI standard that does exactly what I needed (and in the case of MySQL does it in an atomic transaction).

```
$return_value = db_merge('mytable')
            ->key(array('id' => $key))
            ->fields($fields)
            ->updateFields(array(
                'updatedon' => $now,
            ))
            ->execute();
```

The return value is an integer returning 1 for inserts and 2 for updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a silly example of replace syntax.

```
mysql> create table test (
    -> id int,
    -> a int,
    -> b int,
    -> unique (id)
    -> ) engine = myisam;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> replace into test (id,a,b) values (1,4,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> replace into test (id,a,b) values (2,10,3);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+------+
| id   | a    | b    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    4 |    2 |
|    2 |   10 |    3 |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> replace into test (id,a,b) values (1,5,5);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------+------+------+
| id   | a    | b    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    5 |    5 |
|    2 |   10 |    3 |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope it could help you.