# drupal insert or update DB record with only one function

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

similar quest is here: [Help with db query in drupal - if exists update else insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825337/help-with-db-query-in-drupal-if-exists-update-else-insert)

But *drupal_write_record()* third argument is to determine update or insert. Maybe drupal has another function, who self determine insert or update by primary key? Or I should it to program my self?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [db_merge()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_merge/7) function, I think it has the features you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't know if there's a record there already, you probably need to check a bit earlier in your program flow. Normally I'd start the function or whatever with a call to the DB and if I don't get an existing record object, I make a new one from stdClass.

This has two benefits: first, it means that you know about existing data, so you can use it if needs be and not overwrite it blindly. Second: when you get to the point where you write to the DB, you know whether it's INSERT or UPDATE based on whether the object has an id property.

Comment: I every time generate record with two primary keys (no one is auto increment), so I can't check record without test in in DB. I think easiest way is first try to delete record and insert. But I am afraid about table overhead...

Comment: Do you mean a composite key? This won't make a difference to the method I outlined. Just do a SELECT * with that combination of fields in a WHERE clause and see what comes back. Are there any other fields in the table apart from the ones you are using for the key (i.e. is this a many-to-many join table)?

Comment: I have a simple query. So I write universal function myself, because I need it to often.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented function myself:

```
function drupal_write_record2($table, $data, $primaryKeys) {
   $data = (array)$data;

   $query = db_select($table)
      ->fields($table);

   if (is_array($primaryKeys))
      foreach ($primaryKeys as $key)
         $query->condition($key, $data[$key]);
   else
      $query->condition($primaryKeys, $data[$primaryKeys]);

   $update = (bool)$query->execute()->fetchAssoc();

   if ($update)
      return drupal_write_record($table, $data, $primaryKeys);
   else
      return drupal_write_record($table, $data);
}
```